# Angular router-outlet doesnt refresh related pages?

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular. My app has three pages/components : header,sidebar and main-content which depends on sidebar list elements. Sidebar component render and list  :

```
<a  [routerLink]= "['/detail' , item.id]">{{item.placeName}}</a>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>

<br><br><br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <app-place-list></app-place-list>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

and place-details component (is rendered and displayed  )

**place,id,comments are class variable**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id=params.get('id');
    });

    this.doGet();
  }

  doGet(){
    if(this.id){
      this.service.getPlace(this.id).subscribe(res=>{
        this.place=res;
        this.comments=this.place.comments;
      });
    }
  }
```

When clicked list elements works fine but once time. If clicked another elements no updated. I didnt understood. I have appropriate route path  in app-routing.ts

```
{path:"detail/:id",component:PlaceDetailComponent}
```

Why didn't it update place-dettail.component.html in router-outler? Why does it works once ?

Comment: you are just calling `doGet()` once, also outside the subscribe block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `doGet` method in the observable subscription:

```js
ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id=params.get('id');
      this.doGet();
    });
  }

  ...
```

This happens because your component is already loaded so this dont call the `ngOnInit` again. on the other hand if your component was destroy and loaded again then this call this this method again.

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling `doGet()` once, so it will not be called again when route parameter is changed, I would also suggest to chain that request with the `this.activatedRoute.paramMap`, for example using `switchMap` or `mergeMap`:

```ts
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params) => this.service.getPlace(params.get('id')))
  ).subscribe(res => {
     this.place = res;
     this.comments = res.comments;
  });
}
```